# Dockerfile: Postgres initdb does not create default files in data dir

Tags: postgresql, docker, alpine-linux

Still getting my docker sea legs, I am trying to create a container for postgres 14 with alpine linux.

this is my `Dockerfile` so far:

```
FROM alpine:3.15.5
EXPOSE 5432

# update repo, install postgres 14
RUN apk update
RUN apk add gcc make
RUN apk add postgresql14 postgis

# data dir
RUN mkdir /var/lib/postgresql/data
RUN chmod 0700 /var/lib/postgresql/data
RUN chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/data
VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data

# create db cluster as postgres user
USER postgres:postgres
RUN initdb -D /var/lib/postgresql/data

# temp
ENTRYPOINT [ "top" ]
```

The issue I am running into is when I build and run (`docker-compose up --build`), the initdb command runs perfectly, no errors, and the output makes sense, however there is no data in the `/var/lib/postgresql/data` dir which should have all the default postgres configs and db files.

The weird thing is, if I attach the container shell while it is running, and run `initdb -D /var/lib/postgresql/data` it works...

Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong/missing

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` as well for total coverage:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  postgres:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: This happens because you are overriding the content of it with your mount: `- ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data`. I have explained the `docker-compose up` process and its implication with mounts in this answer, if this is of any interest for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769756/composer-install-doesnt-install-packages-when-running-in-dockerfile/46458246#46458246.

Comment: This said, I hope, this trial is to make your hand on docker because there is already a postgres alpine image: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/?tab=tags&page=1&name=alpine

Comment: And so, If you want more insight, just look at what they are doing in their _Dockerfile_ to overcome this: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/tree/2f6878ca854713264ebb27c1ba8530c884bcbca5/14/alpine. Hint: it's all about the entrypoint.

Comment: Thanks a stack @β.εηοιτ.βε you were right I the volume was clearing it. Going to have a look at the postgres link you shared, thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

as @β.εηοιτ.βε has pointed out:

> This happens because you are overriding the content of it with your
> mount: `- ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data`. I have explained the
> docker-compose up process and its implication with mounts [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769756/composer-install-doesnt-install-packages-when-running-in-dockerfile/46458246#46458246).